# Python pandas resample takes too much memory

Tags: python, pandas, out-of-memory, resampling

I have a time series of firm fundamental data like market value, closing price indexed by date, and cusip with weekly frequency. I would like to resample it to get data with monthly frequency but the problem is that my code takes too much memory and too much time for a very little amount of data.

Here is my code:

```
def getMonthlyData(start=(datetime.now()-relativedelta(years=5)),end=datetime.now()):
    _data=getWeeklyData(start,end)
    _startTime=datetime.now()
    _data=_data.unstack('Cusip').resample('M',how=(lambda x:x[-1])).stack('Cusip')
    _endTime=datetime.now()
    print("Time Taken to Resample Data : " + str(_endTime - _startTime))
    _data.sort_index(ascending=[False,True],inplace=True)
    return _data
```

The `getWeeklyData()` function returns the data quickly (if, say, I pull in about two months of data) but after that the program just sort of hangs and the memory consumption goes up significantly.

How can I improve it?

Comment: Using `resample('M', how='last'` will be a little bit faster. But can you show an example dataset (reproducible piece of code)?

Comment: Also, you don't need to use underscored variables in a function, in python an underscore-prefix is used within *classes* to mean attribute/method should be considered non-public.

Comment: Thanks joris and Andy. I tried how='last' but couldnt see any significant improvement. I am thinking of wrapping the function into a cache - http://pythonhosted.org/joblib/memory.html

Comment: Caching the functions help somewhat if I am making repeated calls but it still takes too much time and I think it is because I unstack and stack 'Cusip'. Is there a way I could avoid doing that ?